# Why can you add an attribute to an instance of a subclass of object, but not to an instance of object?

Tags: python, object, attributes

Why does this raise an error:

```
o = object()
o.i = 1
```

But this does not:

```
class A(object):
    pass

a = A()
a.i = 1
```

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because built-in types don't have dictionaries associated with them to hold added attributes:

```
>>> o = object()
>>> dir(o)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

See? No `__dict__`.

But adding a subclass gives the attribute somewhere to go:

```
>>> class A(object):
....    pass
....
>>> a = A()
>>> dir(a)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

Saying that it's "because they're defined in C" isn't a "why". You could certainly define a type in C with an instance dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

`object` is defined in C. You cannot add arbitrary attributes to instances of types defined in C [unless you fill the appropriate slots in the type definition](http://docs.python.org/extending/newtypes.html#attribute-management).

Comment: This implies both that you couldn't define a type in C with an instance dictionary and that implementations not written in C won't have this limitation. Neither is true. "You can't" also isn't an answer to "why can't you".